# Access query doesn't work with DISTINCT and Val()

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

I have a query

```
SELECT col1, Val(col2)
FROM table1;
```

where col2 is a text data type.

I want to use DISTINCT here,

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, Val(col2)
FROM table1;
```

but when I add it, I have an error
"`Data type mismatch in criteria expression`".

I have the same error when I try to sort the column2 (for the first query). Why?

Comment: Edit your question and show the queries that do not work.

Comment: what datatype is col1? and wich column are you wanting to use DISTINCT against? This may help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175258

Comment: Gordon: I wrote that the query with Distinct doesn't work. Why votedown? I edited my question and added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my question.
Because some of the rows have NULL value in col2 and SQL cannot compare two NULLs to find distinct rows, one should add `WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, Val(col2)
FROM table1
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

The Val function doesn't process NULL values. Change your second column to Val(nz(col2,""))